# Syntax error at the if/elif statement, not sure what's causing the error

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.5

I keep getting a syntax error at the if statement, and I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Can anyone help?

```
def draw_square(self, loc, width):

    loc = (x, y)
    for i in range (3):
        width(width)
        turtle.forward(60)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(random.randint(10,100))
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(60)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(random.randint(10, 100))

    if turtle.xcor < or > x:
        x = turtle.xcor
    elif turtle.ycor < or > y:
        y = turtle.ycor

    return self.loc, self.width
```

Comment: What logic test are you trying to do? `turtle.xcor < or > x` is not valid syntax. But if you're wanting to check whether it is greater than or less than ( `if turtle.xcor < x or turtle.xcor > x:` ) then the only time your `elif` clause would work is if `turtle.xcor == x`... Even then, I'm not sure what this is doing

Comment: use `!=` operator instead

Comment: What are `x` and `y` in the first place? Globals? If so, you'll need a `global x, y` line at the top of your function so that they are updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

In think your syntax is invalid in:

```
if turtle.xcor < or > x:
    x = turtle.xcor
elif turtle.ycor < or > y:
    y = turtle.ycor
```

Try to change it for:

```
if turtle.xcor < x or turtle.xcor > x:
    x = turtle.xcor
elif turtle.ycor < y or turtle.ycor > y:
    y = turtle.ycor
```

Comment: use `!=` operator instead  :)

Comment: This is just the same as my comment. But even then, there could be an issue with the `if/elif` depending on what the intended output is.

Comment: Yes i edited the answer, sometimes i send a question/answer/comment and is bad and i must edit it about 3 times :)

Comment: I am sorry i missed read your comment @roganjosh that is the same that my answer.

Comment: I would still make the edit that `!=` is the most appropriate in this case as suggested by @BillBEGUERADJ . One fixes the syntax but that change makes it more readable.